# How to get jquery animate to work in Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using jQuery's `animate()` method in my Rails application.

However, I can't get it to work.

This is my `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I tried adding `//= require jquery-ui` in there but it is causing my application to crash:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: is the `jquery-ui.js` in the js folder?

Comment: what version of `jquery-rails` gem do you have?

Comment: No, I think I don't even have a `js` folder in my app. I have just one file: `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.

Comment: I haven't specified any version for my gem. I just do this in my Gem file: `gem 'jquery-rails'`. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: `jquery-ui.min.js` (which is references by `//= require jquery-ui`) is in my `jquery-rails-2.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts`. Can you locate it in you matching gem. And what's the reason, you use `3.2.8`? Due to recent security issues, it is strongly advised to upgrade to `3.2.13`!

Comment: +1 to what @Martin M said, I came here to post the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally found the solution:

In fact, it's not enough to just add `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` to your gemfile. You also need this line in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails).

Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'jquery-ui-rails' in your Gemfile for jquery-ui related plugins to work.  Please add the following line to  your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

After adding this gem, please run bundle command:

```
bundle
```

Comment: That's strange, could you share the details(OS, rails and ruby versions) of your environment and application?  Just for FYI I'm on rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3 and when I do not have jquery-ui-rails in my Gemfile I get the same message but when I add it back it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have version 3.0.1 of `jquery-rails` / last version now 3.0.1 (you can see version of gem on Gemfile.Lock).

You don't put `//= require jquery-ui` because `jquery-ui` has been remove from gem `jquery-rails` (3.0.0+) see [commit](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/commit/2fdcdb2633cbc6426d412c050200fc31d14b9a3b). If you need jquery-ui, you could use [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) gem.

---

I tried jquery animate() and it's works. I'm on rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3 and gem 'jquery-rails' on Gemfile.

Here's my source code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $('.logo .active-image').animate({
       opacity:1,          //set opacity
       marginTop: "-90px", //move the image 'up' 90px
       }, 5000);           //animate over 5 secs
 });
</script>

<div class="logo">
     <%= image_tag("asus_2.jpg", :class => 'active-image', :height => '100', :width => '123') %>
</div>
```

I think error existing  on your  jquery function. You should check console on your browser (inspect element > console) and you can see error log. You could post error on your question.