# How to get jquery animate to work on Rails 4.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Rails: 4.0.0
Ruby : 1.9.3

I am using jQuery's `animate()` method in my Rails application.

I can't get it to work.

I've read the documentation at [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) and followed the steps mentioned there, i.e.,

1. Installed the gem
2. included it in the Gemfile  - `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`
3. bundle install
4. Added the `//= require jquery.ui.all` in my `application.js` file

Yet I get an `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error.

```
Showing /Users/anil20787/workspace/railsdir/depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
  (in /Users/anil20787/workspace/railsdir/depot/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:14)
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I did also look up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008665/how-to-get-jquery-animate-to-work-in-rails-3-2-8) with a problem similar to mine, but it is pointing to the documentation, whose steps I have already followed. Not sure where I have made a mistake.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your gemfile please?

Comment: just do rake assets:precompile and see...

Comment: this command wrote (or copied) some png files to the directory /projectDirectory/public/assets/jquery-ui/  but the error still persists

Comment: did u bundle install after adding the gem?

Comment: Yes I did. And the output did shown that the gems are being used

`...
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.3)
...`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874265/gem-jquery-ui-rails-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui-all) the order of the includes is important. Can you post your include file?

Put `//= require jquery.ui.all` right after `//= require jquery` so it will look like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require svitla_test
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my Rails server did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still struggle  with this I added `gem 'rails-asset-jqueryui'` then run `bundle install` and after it, restart server... then the file should be found, of course you also need to add

`//= require jquery.ui.all` in `application.js` file

and

`*= require jquery.ui.all` in `applications.css` file

Comment: @Coronelix Good answer but as of 2016, you are better off using `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` as it is maintained and working with Rails 5. The requires are still the same as above. You can also just include what you want like: 
`//= require jquery-ui/effect-highlight`
  and 
`*= require jquery-ui/effect-highlight`